# Domain of $7^{\log_7(x^2-4x+5)}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, logarithms, quadratics

> If $$7^{\log_7(x^2-4x+5)}=x-1$$ then $x$ may have values...

My attempt: $$x^2-4x+5=x-1$$

So, $$x^2-5x+6=0$$

So, $$x=2,3$$

To check the domain of log, $$x^2-4x+5>0$$ i.e., $$(x-2+i)(x-2-i)>0$$ That gives me, $x<2-i$ and $x>2+i$. Is this a valid way of writing domain here? If No, how to write the domain of $7^{\log_7(x^2-4x+5)}$?

Also, if I put the value of $x$ as $2$ or $3$ in the given equation, it satisfies, but if I compare it with the inequalities $x<2-i$ or $x>2+i$, then I am not able to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: "Is this a valid way of writing domain here?" --  No. It's complicated to get into why, but you cannot "order" the complex numbers (i.e. you cannot say any one complex number is "greater than" or "less than" another). That means that $x > 2+i$, for example, doesn't make sense.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a video showing a relatively simple contradiction that would result if we were to claim we could order the complex numbers. -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acCGhA-n5z8

Comment: Thanks @EeveeTrainer. Now, I see why I am not getting satisfactory answer on comparing 2 and 3 with the obtained inequalities.

Comment: Inequalities don't work with complex numbers.

Comment: $x^2-4x+5=(x-2)^2+1>0$ for all $x.$

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews. I wish I had been able to work it out on my own!

Comment: Is there are reason the question $7^{\log_7{x^2-4x + 5}}$ was written as such rather than as $x^2 - 4x + 5$?

Comment: If you are using complex numbers then the domain of $\log_7{f(x)}$ is all of $\mathbb C$.  There is no restriction that $f(x)$ need be positive or real or anything other restriction other than $f:X\to \mathbb C$.  As any complex number can be used as input, then any complex output of $f(x)$ is possible.

Comment: ooop.... there is the restriction that $f(x) \ne 0$.  So the domain is $\mathbb C\setminus f^{-1}(0)$.  In this case all $\mathbb C$ except $2\pm i$.  Which doesn't include $2$ or $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag says "complex numbers".  In complex numbers you do not have any restriction that $x^2 - 4x +5$ must be positive.  It could be negative or even non-real.  But it can't be $0$.

so your only restriction is that $x \ne 2\pm i$.

Also there is no order in complex numbers.  $x < 2-i$ does not make sense.

So if you are working with Complex numbers the domain is all $x$ so that $x^2 -4x +5 \ne 0$ or all complex except $2\pm i$.  $2$ and $3$ are within that domain so you are safe.

If you are working with Real numbers the domain is all $x$ where $x^2 -4x + 5 = (x-2)^2 + 1 > 0$.  This is all real numbers.  $2$ and $3$ are within that domain so you are safe.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x^2-4x+5 = (x-2)^2 +1 >0 $$ for all x, so there is no problem with logarithm and we have
$$7^{log_7(x^2-4x+5)}=x^2-4x+5$$

Therefore $$ 7^{log_7(x^2-4x+5)}=x-1 \iff x^2-5x+6=0$$

Thus the  solutions are $x=2$ and $x=3$

Comment: He's working with complex numbers.  So $x^4 -4x +5 $ being positive is not an issue.